# How to assign values of one list to values of second list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

How can i concatenate values from List A to that of List B for e.g

```
ListA = [1,2,3,4,5]
ListB = ["a","b","c","d","e"]
```

so output should return something like

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

I have multiple rows (26k) with such list of variable lengths (but number of entries match in both lists for every row) and one output is required for each row

Comment: `dict(zip(ListB,ListA))` would do.

Comment: as a list `["{}={}".format(*c) for c in zip(ListB,listA)]`. But your examples aren't syntaxically valid (specially the result. Please [edit] for clarity

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre isn't that a list of strings and not dict?

Answer (score 1):

You could make it into a dictionary and add each item to that dictionary like this

```py
ListA = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ListB = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

ListC = []
# Generate a number for every item in ListA
for i in range(len(ListA)):
    # Take that number and use it as an index to append the value from ListA and ListB to ListC as a dictionary
    ListC.append({str(ListA[i]): ListB[i]})
# Print ListC
print(ListC)

"""
Output:
[{'1': 'a'}, {'2': 'b'}, {'3': 'c'}, {'4': 'd'}, {'5': 'e'}]
"""
```

To get the output of the dictionary, you can print it using `print(ListC[0]['1'])` which will output the letter "a". The Zero is the index marker (which always starts at zero in python), so if you wanted to print a specific number's corresponding letter, you could just take the number, subtract one and place it in the first set of `[]`.

Say I wanted the letter for '5'.

```py
# Number for the letter we want
num = "5"
# Calculate it's position in the dictionary
index = int(num) - 1
# Print that character
print(ListC[index][num])

"""
Output:
'e'
"""
```

The way you want it to be output is not syntactically correct for Python, and this is the alternative.

Comment: Thanks a lot! yes my syntax was wrong, which i have corrected now.

Comment: Could you please mark an answer to the question? That way if someone else comes looking they see who answered it

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with same size multiple lists, `zip` is your friend

As a list of strings, just use `format` and feed it the tuple that `zip` returns

```
ListA = [1,2,3,4,5]
ListB = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

result_as_list = ["{}={}".format(*c) for c in zip(ListB,ListA)]
```

As a dictionary (maybe better as it doesn't need back parsing of the string to get key & value), just feed `zip` to `dict` constructor:

```
result_as_dict = dict(zip(ListB,ListA))
```

output:

```
>>> result_as_list
['a=1', 'b=2', 'c=3', 'd=4', 'e=5']
>>> result_as_dict
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jean, yes syntax is wrong and sorry for this, i am pretty much new to Python.